# integration with CIB MasterCard gives CORS policy blocked

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

when I am trying connect to the "MasterCard session API" with adding in header 'authorization' and 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'
I received below error

> "Access to XMLHttpRequest at
>   'https://cibpaynow.gateway.mastercard.com/form/version/53/merchant/{merchantID}/session'
>   from origin 'https://MyProductionURL' has been blocked by CORS policy:
>   Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource."

how to solve this CORS and if there are any workaround
i am working under C# MVC => Ajax
note: when i disable the security in the chrome it work good

Please advise.

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'https://cibpaynow.gateway.mastercard.com/form/version/53/merchant/{merchantID}/session',
    headers: {
        'authorization': 'Bearer  ' + btoa('{merchantID}:{Password}'),
        'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': 'https://cibpaynow.gateway.mastercard.com',
        //'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'
        //'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': 'https://MyProductionURL' 
    },
    data: {},
    success: function (result) {
    },
    error: function (err) { console.log(err.statusText) }
});
```

Comment: Perhaps you should avoid making this call on the browser, for security purposes. Any user can take the merchantID/password just by looking in the code.

Comment: Did u find the solution?

Comment: @ZeeshanMalik yes i had change the way to integrate with c# code behind not client side and work good